# What is the most restrictive way to allow IPv6 ICMP requests on iptables?

Tags: iptables, ipv6

This is what I have so far but it is pretty open.

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
-A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

If you have time, explaining the rules would be amazing.

Comment: A reference: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4890

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/452880/what-are-the-essential-iptables-rules-for-ipv6-to-work-properly https://resources.sei.cmu.edu/tools/downloads/vulnerability-analysis/assets/IPv6/ip6tables_rules.txt