# Is it recommended to drop all traffic by default in iptables after accepting only what is required?

Tags: iptables

I was told using `iptables -P OUTPUT DROP` after rules such as `iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT` to accept what is required didn’t do much from a security standpoint. Is that true?

This is what I am been using for some time (planning on implementing some SSH brute force rules shortly):

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m state --state NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Comment: Try this google search "firewall best practice" each one will say to have a "default deny" at the end...  [Like this](https://www.ncsc.gov.uk/collection/10-steps-to-cyber-security/the-10-steps/network-security#id-3.NetworkSecurity-Howcantheriskbemanaged?:~:text=The%20firewall%20rule%20set%20should%20deny%20traffic%20by%20default)

Comment: @schroeder That was my gut feeling but wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 3):

Let me be blunt: "default deny" is the best practice. The concept is that the firewall blocks all traffic, and only allows the specific traffic that is approved.

#### But wait! What could those people mean that it doesn't add anything?

It's logic: without the `DROP`, if a packet does not match any rule, then the firewall doesn't do anything with it. There is no instruction for what to do with it. So it should just die, right?

#### However

That assumes that the system will behave in a consistent and predictable way when there is no matching rule. But you cannot be so sure about that.

A default deny rule is a safety net that ensures that the firewall will act like a firewall.

Comment: Thanks! Would you happen to know a good guide to harden IPv6 ICMP iptables rules to only accept what is required to not break IPv6 traffic?

Comment: It depends on the type of IPv6 traffic you need... Lots of IPv6 firewall guides out there.

Comment: I am writing a strongSwan guide (see https://draft.sunknudsen.com/privacy-guides/how-to-self-host-a-hardened-strongswan-ikev2-ipsec-vpn-server-for-ios-and-macos#step-16-configure-iptables) so IPv6 traffic routed through the VPN to the Internet and traffic such as outbound http and ntp requests. I have spent a considerable amount of time researching this but what I found appears to be inconsistent and rarely mentions `OUTPUT` rules. I am worried an open question like that would be closed here.

Comment: For IPv4, I have been dropping ICMP altogether and everything works fine.

Comment: See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/235139/what-is-the-most-restrictive-way-to-allow-ipv6-icmp-requests-on-iptables

Answer (score 0):

I have found adding a default rule at the end to drop is better than having a default policy.

If you flush your rules, your default policy does not flush. If you are not physically on the server or a KVM attached to the server, you will immediately take down all traffic to your server (including your own session). At best, you then have to reboot. At worst recovery is more.... complex.

Comment: Welcome. This answer is about the difference between a rule and a policy. The question is about the use of either. You don't address the question directly.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).